# How to mock a random number generator object in python

Tags: random, generator, python-unittest.mock

I am writing a unit test for a function and in the real function I have:

```
rng = default_rng()
...
... # a little while later
while N<50:
    ...
    idx = rng.integers(100)
```

How do I mock out either the variable idx or the call to rng.integers?  In other words, I'd like to make idx pull from a simple ordered list [0, 1, 2, ...].

Every time I try `@mock.patch('numpy.random.default_rng', side_effects=[0, 1, 2, ...])` decorating the test function, the code 'runs' but doesn't do what I am hoping.  If I replace the above to 'numpy.random.default_rng.integers I get an error that says default_rng has no attribute integers (I believe bc it is a generator object).  I've tried a number of different iterations using @mock.patch.object but still to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your patching. First, you are obviously using `from numpy.random import default_rng`, so you have to patch the `default_rng` instance in your module - see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Second, `integers` is called on the instance of `default_rng`, not on the class, so you first have to get the instance of the mock, with is done via `return_value`.

And third: it's called `side_effect`, not `side_effects` (though that may just be a typo in your question).

So a working version could look like this (adapted a bit to actually be able to test something):

*sut.py*

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng

def get_random():
    rng = default_rng()
    idx = 0
    while idx < 50:
        idx = rng.integers(100)
    return idx
```

*test_sut.py*

```py
@mock.patch('sut.default_rng')
def test_get_random(mocked):
    mocked.return_value.integers.side_effect = range(60)
    assert do_something() == 50
```

Comment: This is really helpful and definitely I am getting a lot further.  I have tried doing what you suggest but when I print idx it gives "<MagicMock name = 'default_rng().integers()' I'd = 140...28>"  how come it doesn't show me a integer i.e 0, 1, 2 ... from the range in side effect?  (And yes side effects was a typo)

Comment: I have tested the code I showed, and it works for me (both in Python 3.7 and 3.10). You should try to convert the range generator to a list explicitely - I changed the answer accordingly - though something must be different in your code, I guess.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I got it.  You were right - my apologies what I did not show bc I didn't think it was important was that I am also mocking out another function call but in doing so I had the ordering wrong.  Once I flipped them your solution is working perfectly.   Thanks again so much for your help!

Comment: I thought they were behaving as keyword arguments when instead they were positional.

Comment: That's fixtures that behave like keyword arguments, not patch arguments, as they don't have a fix name. You could use the `mocker` fixture from `pytest-mock` instead of the decorator for convenience.